# Problem with table of contents

Tags: table-of-contents

I got a problem with the table of contents. I can not see the list of figures or tables include it. They are not present, even when they are before the Introduction  and have the roman numeration.

What can I do to include them?

Comment: Nobdy here is omniscient... well, maybe egreg is. Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Real quick: Did you provide the commands `\listoffigures` and `\listoftables`? I assume you did, but since you don't mention having done so... You refer to "roman numeration" -- of what: pages? or something else? Do you load a package such as `tocloft` to influence the creation of the Table of Contents? Please provide an MWE

Answer (score 4):

The simplest method I can think of is to use the »[tocbibind](http://ctan.rg/pkg/tocbibind)« package.

```
\documentcetholass[11pt]{report}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}

\begin{document}
  \tableofcontents
  \listoffigures
  \listoftables

  \chapter{Foo}

  \begin{figure}[!htb]
    \centering
    \rule{4in}{2.25in}
    \caption{Dummy figure}
    \label{fig:dummy}
  \end{figure}

  \begin{table}[!htb]
    \caption{Dummy figure}
    \label{tab:dummy}
    \centering
    \rule{4in}{2.25in}
  \end{table}
\end{document}
```

---

[image]

Answer (score 3):

This is typically the case in the default document class since both the LoF and LoT (including the ToC) is issued as a `\chapter*` (unnumbered chapter). And, as is apparent, these don't make their way into the ToC. Why? See the definition of `\@schapter` in comparison to that of `\@chapter` (from [`report.cls`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/unpacked/report.cls)):

```
\def\@chapter[#1]#2{\ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
                         \refstepcounter{chapter}%
                         \typeout{\@chapapp\space\thechapter.}%
                         \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}% Add \chapter to ToC
                                   {\protect\numberline{\thechapter}#1}%
                    \else
                      \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#1}%
                    \fi
                    \chaptermark{#1}%
                    \addtocontents{lof}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}% Insert gap in LoF
                    \addtocontents{lot}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}% Insert gap in LoT
                    \if@twocolumn
                      \@topnewpage[\@makechapterhead{#2}]%
                    \else
                      \@makechapterhead{#2}%
                      \@afterheading
                    \fi}
\def\@schapter#1{\if@twocolumn
                   \@topnewpage[\@makeschapterhead{#1}]%
                 \else
                   \@makeschapterhead{#1}%
                   \@afterheading
                 \fi}
```

`\@chapter` (associated with `\chapter`) goes through great lengths to set up the numbering and include it in the ToC (via `\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{...}`). None of that appear in `\@schapter` (associated with `\chapter*`). So, if you wish to make this happen, you can insert the appropriate line of code manually:

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\clearpage\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Figures}% Add LoF to ToC
\listoffigures
%\clearpage\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Tables}% Add LoT to ToC
\listoftables
\chapter{A chapter}
\begin{figure}\caption{A figure}\end{figure}
\begin{table}\caption{A table}\end{table}
\end{document}
```

In the above MWE, I've only added the LoF to the ToC to show the difference. The usage of `\addcontentsline{<file>}{<style>}{<stuff>}` inserts `<stuff>` with style `<style>` into the file `\jobname.<file>`. Each sectional unit (or sometimes a floating object) has a different style/formatting. In this case, since `\listoffigures` (and `\listoftables`) are both `\chapter*`s, I'm formatting with the same `<style>` as `chapter`.

Comment: Based on the OP's very *minimal* (pej.) question, I consider your answer a (praiseworthy) shot in the dark.